# Determine if page was refreshed OR navigated to via a direct link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am needing to determine if the page was loaded from a direct link, if it is I need to run an action, but currently how I have it written a page refresh also triggers this action. Is there another way to determine the page was direct linked into (meaning they did not get to the page by clicking some other link or button within the site, but instead they copied and pasted the link in to URL bar)

This is what I am currently doing which is running into the above problem:

```
const history = useHistory();
if (history.action === 'POP') {
   //trigger action
   //this currently triggers on page refresh because action returns POP
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.referrer` property returns the URI of the page that linked to the current page.

This property is empty for direct URL entries.

Comment: hmm it seems to be empty for every use case for me. It is empty on direct link, refresh or if I navigate to it from within the site. I am just simply printing it to the console right now. `console.log(document.referrer)`

Comment: @Cookies The meta tag's referrer settings might be blocking this. Or some browsers... I think `document.referrer` with sessionStorage can be used to distinguish directly accessed users.